# A continuous locally injection on $\mathbb{S}^1$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $\mathbb{S}^1$(of course its topology induced from $\mathbb{R}^2$) denote the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$, $f:\mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ be a continuous mapping, if for any $x\in \mathbb{S}^1$, there exist an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, such that $f$ is an injection on $U$, then $f$ is an injection.

Is this right? If it is, prove it. If not, give me a counterexample.

Of course for $\mathbb{S}^1$ is a compact Hausdorff space, so $f$ is a closed mapping and $f(\mathbb{S}^1)$ is a closed arc in $\mathbb{S^1}$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No. What you can prove is that $f$ is a covering map.

Comment: @MikeMiller I think you mean to say that you can prove that $f$ is surjective, not that it's a [covering map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space) in the topological sense.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: Thanks for the comment, but my comment says what I meant it to.

Comment: @DavidChan: Its image is compact and connected subset of the interval. If it wasn't surjective, its image would be homeomorphic to an arc $[a,b]$. Then pick a point $x \in S^1$ such that $f(x) = a$. Local injectivity gets you a contradiction. To prove that it's a covering map as in my first comment, you use this and you prove that it's also a local homeomorphism and use these as your toolkit.

Comment: @MikeMiller I know what you mean, but I still have two question. First, how to prove for any $y \in Y$, there exist $U(y)$ such that $f^(-1)(U)$ is the union of some disjoint open subset. And the second, for here, $f$ is an open, closed mapping, a surjection, even though $f$ is a covering mapping, $f$ is still maybe an injection.

Comment: You can come up with non-injective covering maps from the circle to itself. Re: the first question: once you prove that $f$ is a local homeomorphism, google "proper local homeomorphisms are covering maps", a question which has been proved on this site numerous times.

Comment: @MikeMiller Ah, sorry, you're right - I misread the question in a silly way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that we have the following counterexample $\Bbb S^1=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\}$, $f(z)=z^2$.